Does removing permission from parent have any impact when inheritence is broken?
https://support.microsoft.com/en-au/office/sharing-sharepoint-folder-items-with-unique-permissions-01e5e32a-a2c5-4d84-ab4c-637f5f642935

In the following example, existing edit permissions are not removed:
Folder A  contains two files.
User A  has read access to one file and has edit access to the other
file.
Admin  or another user shares Folder A with view permissions to User
A. (Then, both files have view permissions).
User A clicks the invite/share link to Folder A.
User A can still edit the file to which they had edit access.

At step 2, since user has read and edit access to a file, that means the inheritence has been broken on the file level?

To prevent User A from editing the file, use either of the following
options:
Option 1 — Change permissions on the file directly (grant only view
permissions to UserA).
Option 2 — Stop sharing the folder to UserA. This removes permissions
to all subfiles and folders. Then, create a new share on the folder
that has view permissions.

Now following option 2 when an admin stops sharing folder with user A, how does it remove the file level permissions of user A? Does removing permission from parent have any impact when inheritence is broken?
